# Understanding events inside modal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this below snippet of code from modal.js a bootstrap3.0 modal plugin , its just 
  like a normal Jquery plugin , please have a look at the below lines of code .

```
 $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
        this.$element
          .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(this.hideModal, this))
          .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
        this.hideModal()
```

now if you have a look at at the 3rd line I.E.

```
  .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(this.hideModal, this))
```

now what functionality is this custom event name/namespace adding to the plugin , when will 
      this event typically fire ? do custom event name/namespaces need to be difined  before they can be 
      used in a function line on or one ??

i understand that Jquery allows custom namespacing for event , and its useful for turning off 
      ONLY THAT PERTICULAR EVENT HANDLER . eg.

```
  $('lala').on('click.randomname' , function(){
          alert('success');
  }); 

  $('lala').off('click.randomname');
```

but somehow i don't understand what functionality the below line of code is adding to the modal.js plugin .

```
  .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(this.hideModal, this))
```

i understand that when the bsTransitionEnd event fired the hideModal function will execute, 
      but when will the bsTransitionEnd event fire at all ?? where is that defined .

I would appreciate a simple explaination of my question . The entire plugin can be found here , [line 124](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L124).

Answer (score 0):

> now what functionality is this custom event name/namespace adding to the plugin , when will this event typically fire ? do custom event name/namespaces need to be difined before they can be used in a function line on or one ??

1. The event will fire when the transition ends
2. You can use whatever event name you want to refer to [mdn docs on CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) and [jQuery Custom Event](http://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/)